# How to add the tilt effect in google map in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

[image]I have added the following lines in my code to tilt the google map:

```
GMSCameraPosition* camera =
    [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:currentPosition zoom:20 bearing:self.locationManager.heading.trueHeading viewingAngle:30];
  _googleMapView.camera = camera;

    self.googleMapView.settings.tiltGestures = YES;
```

But it does not work.I can't find any tilt effect in my google map view by adding the above code.Here I have added two images.I'm getting the map like the second image.But,I need the map like the 1st image.
[image] Please help.

Comment: can you post a gif or video of what you need?

Comment: yeah sure.I have added the images.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the _googleMapView.camera property directly use this method instead:

```
[_googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
```

EDIT:
You can also use the following if you only want to change the camera tilt:

```
[_googleMapView animateToViewingAngle:30.0]
```

Just note that the angle needs to be between 30 and 45 degrees (Or 0 if you want the straight down view).

Comment: Can I get the tilt view in simulator, or I should check it on device?@Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4.2**

You can tilt the google mapview using [animate(toViewingAngle: )](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#viewing_angle) function.

```
googleMapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
```